# In Angular2 directives, why are the observers called host?

Tags: angular

In an Angular2 directive decorator:

```
@Directive ({
    selector: "[autoGrow]",
    host: {
        "(focus)": "onFocus()",
        "(blur)": "onBlur()"
    } 
})
```

the `host` are the observers, on what event, and which handler.  What does "host" mean in this context?

Answer (score 2):

Directive is bound to host element:

```
<input autoGrow>
```

`<input>` is called host in this context.

`(focus)` and `(blur)` are actually events dispatched by host, it is the same as adding listeners directly to `input`:

```
<input (focus)="onFocus()" (blur)="onBlur()">
```

Comment: if we can use `<input (focus)="onFocus()" (blur)="onBlur()">`, does that mean the `host:` part actually can be more than just the events and handlers?

Comment: Yes, you can defined input/output names, styles, bindings, but documentation is really poor.

Answer (score 1):

Host means the DOM element that hosts this component.

- `(focus)...` means to listen on events on the component itself
- `[class.someClass]...` means to add/remove a class on the component itself
- ...

Comment: isn't *everything* about this DOM element?  so, wouldn't a name such as `listeners` or `observers` make more sense than `host` because it is about the event listeners and handlers?

Comment: I guess this is about some distinction between the DOM element (host) and the class instance which is something different. There is also the view (children of the host element). I think it's valid to make this explicit.

Answer (score 1):

`host` means that you will configure something against the element the directive applies on.

In you case, you register handlers for the `focus` and `blur` events of the element.

Such handlers will be defined into the directive class. For example when the element has the focus, the `onFocus` method will be called.

```
@Directive ({
  selector: "[autoGrow]",
  host: {
    "(focus)": "onFocus()",
    "(blur)": "onBlur()"
  } 
})
export class MyDirective {
  onFocus() {
    // handle focus event
  }

  onBlur() {
    // handle blur event
  }
}
```